# Change of variables in $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{-\beta}}{1+x} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

Let $0 < \beta < \frac{1}{2}$. I cannot figure out which change of variable to use in order to prove that :

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x^{-\beta}}{1+x} \; dx = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{-\beta}}{1+x} (1+x^{2\beta-1}) \; dx $$

I have tried : $t=\frac{1}{1+x}$ and $t=\frac{x}{1+x}$ but it didn't work.

Comment: $\large{\pi \over \sin\left(\pi\beta\right)}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split into two pieces; the integral is equal to

$$\int_0^1 dx \frac{x^{-\beta}}{1+x} + \underbrace{\int_1^{\infty} dx \frac{x^{-\beta}}{1+x}}_{x\mapsto 1/x} $$

which is then

$$\int_0^1 dx \frac{x^{-\beta}}{1+x} + \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{x^2} \frac{x^{\beta}}{1+(1/x)}  = \int_0^1 dx \frac{x^{-\beta}}{1+x} + \int_0^1 dx \frac{x^{\beta-1}}{1+x}$$

which is, combining,

$$\int_0^1 dx  \frac{x^{-\beta}}{1+x} \left ( 1+ x^{2 \beta-1}\right ) $$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{t \equiv {1 \over 1 + x}\quad\iff\quad x = {1 - t \over t}}$:
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-\beta} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x&=
\int_{1}^{0}t\pars{1 - t \over t}^{-\beta}\pars{-\,{\dd t \over t^{2}}}
=
\int_{0}^{1}t^{\beta - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{-\beta}\,\dd t
={\rm B}\pars{\beta,1 - \beta}
\end{align}
where ${\rm B}\pars{x,y}$ is the *Beta Function* which satisfies
$\ds{{\rm B}\pars{x,y} = {\Gamma\pars{x}\Gamma\pars{y} \over \Gamma\pars{x + y}}}$. Then,
\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{-\beta} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x}&=
{\Gamma\pars{\beta}\Gamma\pars{1 - \beta} \over \Gamma\pars{\beta + \bracks{1 - \beta}}} = \color{#00f}{\large{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi\beta}}}
\end{align}
Here we used the identities
$\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}\Gamma\pars{1 - z} = {\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi z}}}$ and $\ds{\Gamma\pars{1} = 1}$.